Problem with sectors Mindustry modding json
I have a problem with sectors. The game crashes when entering a sector. I don't know what this is, please tell me
Error:
Mindustry has crashed. How unfortunate.
Version: steam build 146
OS: Windows 10 x64 (amd64)
Java Version: 16.0.1
Runtime Available Memory: 4072mb
Cores: 4
Mods: mars-mod:1

arc.util.serialization.SerializationException: Serialization trace:
{}.sector
sector (mindustry.game.Rules)
    at arc.util.serialization.Json.readFields(Json.java:914)
    at arc.util.serialization.Json.readValue(Json.java:1095)
    at arc.util.serialization.Json.readValue(Json.java:990)
    at arc.util.serialization.Json.fromJson(Json.java:831)
    at mindustry.io.JsonIO.read(JsonIO.java:61)
    at mindustry.io.SaveVersion.getMeta(SaveVersion.java:59)
    at mindustry.io.SaveIO.getMeta(SaveIO.java:93)
    at mindustry.io.SaveIO.getMeta(SaveIO.java:80)
    at mindustry.game.Saves$SaveSlot.save(Saves.java:225)
    at mindustry.game.Saves.saveSector(Saves.java:155)
    at mindustry.core.Control.playNewSector(Control.java:521)
    at mindustry.core.Control.lambda$playSector$33(Control.java:508)
    at mindustry.core.UI.lambda$loadAnd$10(UI.java:268)
    at arc.util.Timer$1.run(Timer.java:88)
    at arc.util.TaskQueue.run(TaskQueue.java:17)
    at arc.backend.sdl.SdlApplication.loop(SdlApplication.java:194)
    at arc.backend.sdl.SdlApplication.<init>(SdlApplication.java:54)
    at mindustry.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "sectors" because the return value of "mindustry.core.ContentLoader.getByName(mindustry.ctype.ContentType, String)" is null
    at mindustry.io.JsonIO$3.read(JsonIO.java:108)
    at mindustry.io.JsonIO$3.read(JsonIO.java:98)
    at arc.util.serialization.Json.readValue(Json.java:1102)
    at arc.util.serialization.Json.readFields(Json.java:907)
    ... 17 more

My mod is called planet mars. I understand that the game cannot find some value (it is null).
Link to mod (Yandex disk): https://disk.yandex.ru/d/ZuhyaWceknciMQ
I changed the sector instead of the serpulo planet and put mars, but nothing changed.
